# Pyautogui.screenshot() cant get function to work how I would like

Tags: python, pyautogui

enter code hereThere is most likely something very obviously wrong here, I'm very new to coding.
I want to take a screenshot when the function pygui.screenshot() is passed, I want the screenshot name to have a numerical value based on how many screenshots have been taken, with the current code when the script is ran no file seems to be saved and have no screenshots in the default nor specified directory

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tess 

screenshot_name = 1


def pyautogui_screenshot():
    global screenshot_name
    screenshot_path = f"Screenshots/screenshot_{screenshot_name}.png"
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot.save(screenshot_path)
    screenshot_name += 1
pyautogui.screenshot()
```

I have also tried

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tess 

screenshot_name = 1


def pyautogui_screenshot():
    global screenshot_name
    screenshot_path = f"screenshot_{screenshot_name}.png"
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot.save(screenshot_path)
    screenshot_name += 1
pyautogui.screenshot()
```

I expected/hoped a png screenshot would appear in the screenshots folder. named screenshot_1.png
instead no png is the directory, I have not searched the entire rood folder as there is alot of files but I did look in the pyautogui folder

Comment: At no point do you actually *call* the `pyautogui_screenshot()` function that you defined.  Instead you call `pyautogui.screenshot()`, which doesn't save anything.

Comment: jasonharper beat me to identifying that issue by about 30 seconds.  If you fix that, then your code shoiuld work, and it will try to save the files in the given filepath relative to where you execute the script from.    I would advise against using the `global` keyword here.  Instead, have the main script track the current count, and pass the number to your function as a parameter, or alternatively have the main program loop figure out the file path and pass the filepath to your function.

Comment: I also want to add: you don't need to do `screenshot.save()`, instead, delete that line, and replace the `pyautogui.screenshot()` line with: `pyautogui.screenshot(screenshot_path)`, since pyautogui allows you to include the argument directly in the screenshot function. No need to screenshot, then save.